# NumPy: How to retrieve the indices of the maximum values in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

With the following array:

```
In [103]: da                                                                                         
Out[103]: 
array([[[ 6, 22,  3],
        [ 4,  9, 20],
        [21, 16,  0]],

       [[ 2, 25, 11],
        [ 5, 17, 18],
        [23, 13,  7]],

       [[10, 14, 26],
        [ 8,  1, 19],
        [15, 12, 24]]])

In [104]: da.shape                                                                                   
Out[104]: (3, 3, 3)
```

The indices of the element with the maximum value can be determined with the following:

```
In [114]: np.unravel_index(np.argmax(da), da.shape)                                                  
Out[114]: (2, 0, 2)
```

and checked:

```
In [115]: da[2, 0, 2]                                                                                
Out[115]: 26
```

But would one determine, without looping/iterating, the 9 indices containing the maximum values for each group of integers `da[:, i1, i2]` where where `i1` and `i2` are 0, 1 or 2?

For example, the group `da[:, 0, 0]` is 6, 2 and 10. The maximum value is 10 and its indices are `da[2, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Are you looking for the `axis` argument to `argmax`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I tried that but the indices returned by `np.unravel_index(np.argmax(da, axis=x), da.shape)` are mostly zeros.

Comment: I've posted an answer showing how to do it correctly. You should really almost never need to ever unravel indices if you craft things carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axis` argument allows you to specify a single axis of operation:

```
i0 = np.argmax(da, axis=0)
```

This means that `i0` is a `(3, 3)` array containing the index of the maximum for each corresponding `i1`, `i2`. The maximum for any `i1`, `i2` in your example is

```
da[i0[i1, i2], i1, i2]
```

Comment: @user2309803. No problem, glad it worked out for you.